# Circular dependencies on angular modules using typescript

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, angular-mock, angular-module

I'm facing this issue where i have 2 angular 1.5 modules that depend on each other, which is fine by angularjs, but when i import them using typescript & webpack, i get circular typescript-module dependencies and the modules are not loaded properly.
I dont have circular dependencies in the angular services between the modules, therefor there should be no problem depending the angular-modules on each other.

```
//first.module.ts
import {SecondModule} from "second.module.ts";
let FirstModule = angular.module("firstModule",[SecondModule.name]);
export {FirstModule};

//second.module.ts
import {FirstModule} from "first.module.ts";
let SecondModule = angular.module("secondModule",[FirstModule.name]);
export {SecondModule};
```

In the example above, i get "cannot get 'name' of undefined" on the last line, since FirstModule is not exported yet.

One solution i saw online is just to not define the SecondModule as a dependency of FirstModule, but make them both dependencies of a parent module (my main app module), the problem is that i cant mock FirstModule using ngMock for unit testing - since it does not register SecondModule as a dependent sub-module. so i have to mock my whole main app which is big and messy.

Other solution i saw was to wrap the angular-modules with typescript classes, and put the angular module creation in the constructor of this class, so i can control when the module is created, but then i have to refactor my whole application to create objects of those wrapped modules, and i have no idea how will this affect writing unit tests using ngMock.

Are there any best practices for this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export a string constant as the first thing in the file

```
//first.module.ts
export const prefixFirstModule = "prefixFirstModule";
import {prefixSecondModule} from "second.module";
export const FirstModule = angular.module(prefixFirstModule,[prefixSecondModule]);

//second.module.ts
export const prefixSecondModule = "prefixSecondModule";
import {prefixFirstModule} from "first.module";
export const SecondModule = angular.module(prefixSecondModule,[prefixFirstModule]);
```

It's a bit of a pain, but as far as I'm aware it's the only way round the problem with the same support for tree shaking etc with your current module structure.

Comment: sounds good, i guess i can also export just the name of the module instead of the angular module itself, and get the same result.
but what about best practice for angular modules using typescript?
there is no need or advantage for a wrapper class for modules?

Comment: I can't think of an advantage of doing it that way, it doesn't mean it doesn't mean there aren't any ;)

Comment: for sure though, there is no *need* for them